# Is there any Windows API that can "normalize" or "maximize" a window?

Tags: ruby, winapi

I was using Ruby's Win32API to `MoveWindow` to move a window and resize it.

But if the window is minimized, it won't show.

`SetWindowPos` works too, and has a flag to hide or show the window, but it is to only make a window visible or invisible, not about minimizing or normalizing.

I also tried `SetForegroundWindow` and `SetActiveWindow` and they won't work either.  Is there a call to make a window normalized or maximized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE)` may be what you're looking for.  See: [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: may also want to call SetForegroundWindow() so that the window appears in front